# Error with jQuery contains()

Tags: jquery

The following statement yields an error:

> TypeError: $(...).children(...).contains is not a function

```
$('.woocommerce-checkout .shop_table tr.cart_item dl.variation').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('.variation-Billing').contains("Once Off")) {
        $(this).children('.variation-Billing').contains("Once Off").show().siblings('.variation-Billing').show();
    }
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Show us your HTML code.

Comment: Show your full code or make a fiddle link.

Comment: Maybe you get fooled by [$.contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) which has nothing to do with [:contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). But error is correct, jQuery has no method `$.fn.contains()` as you are trying to use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct; 'contains' is not a method - it's a selector, use `:contains()`.

Also note that the `if` statement should check the `length` property of the jQuery object to see if any elements were found. Try this:

```
$('.woocommerce-checkout .shop_table tr.cart_item dl.variation').each(function() {
    var $oneOffBillings = $(this).children('.variation-Billing:contains("Once Off")');
    if ($oneOffBillings.length) {
        $oneOffBillings.show().siblings('.variation-Billing').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, thanks @Rory McCrossan! Actually I want to show elements NOT containing "Once Off"

Comment: In that case combine the `:not` selector, like this: `:not(:contains("Once Off"))`

Comment: Thanks, like this? $(this).children('.variation-Billing:not(:contains("Once Off"))').show().siblings('.variation-Billing').show(); Doesn't seem to work - I don't get any error though

Comment: That's the correct usage. If it doesn't fit your case it would be worth starting a new question about it - but make sure to include the JS and HTML code.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work. $(this).children('.variation-Billing:first-child:not(:contains("Once Off"))'); actually selects all elements (no matter what they contain)